# How does JVM resolve overridden and overriding methods in java

Tags: java, polymorphism

As per my knowledge about polymorphism in C++ ( Plz correct me if I am wrong )

For run time polymorphism in C++, Compiler maintain two things first vptr for every object and vtable for every class. Whenever we call an overridden method, the compiler first fetch the vptr of the referenced object and then it goes to the vtable of the corresponding class and then fetch the address of the appropriate method and execute.

Now my question is,

How JVM perform this task ??

Does it also maintain a vtable ??

How an overridden and overriding method is stored in method area ??

What actually happens behind the scene when we call a overriding method from subclass by using super class reference referring to subclass object ??

Comment: I believe this will be implementation-dependent.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, will you please explain by considering any of appropriate implementations ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in the specification of [`invokevirtual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual)

> Let C be the class of *objectref*. The actual method to be invoked is selected by the following lookup procedure:
>
> - If C contains a declaration for an instance method m that overrides (§5.4.5) the resolved method, then m is the method to be invoked, and the lookup procedure terminates.
> - Otherwise, if C has a superclass, this same lookup procedure is performed recursively using the direct superclass of C; the method to be invoked is the result of the recursive invocation of this lookup procedure.
> - Otherwise, an `AbstractMethodError` is raised.